# Use Tktable to add combobox into a cell

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How to use Tktable package to realize the sample result, add a combobox into a cell? Or is there any other package that can be used to realized it conveniently? Thanks! [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVjh5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should try executing something on your own first and then post what you've tried and ask specific questions where you are stuck. Simply reading the documentation will get you something that looks like this.

```
package require Tktable
package require Ttk

pack [table .t -cols 5 -rows 5 -variable tabarray]
set cb [ttk::combobox .t.cb]

array set tabarray [list 1,0 1 2,0 2 3,0 3 4,0 4]
array set tabarray [list 0,1 "Layer Name" 0,2 Transmission 0,3 Phase 0,4 Nested]

.t window config 1,1 -window $cb -sticky news
```

Or if you want to accomplish the same without using a tktable, you can leverage the grid geometry that comes with Tk. But you're probably better off using the table because it manages the geometry for you, provides column and row expansion, etc.

```
package require Ttk

set coltitles {"Layer Name" "Transmission" "Phase" "Nested"}

# Frame to hold the 'cells'
grid [frame .f] -row 0 -column 0 -sticky news
grid columnconfigure .f {1 2 3 4} -weight 1 -uniform 1

# Row numbers
for {set row 1} {$row < 5} {incr row} {
    # Row labels
    grid [label .f.tr$row -text $row -anchor e -relief groove -bd 1 -width 2] -row $row -column 0 -sticky news
}

# Column titles
for {set col 1} {$col < 5} {incr col} {
    grid [label .f.tc$col -text [lindex $coltitles [expr $col - 1]] -anchor c -relief groove -bd 1] -row 0 -column $col -sticky news
}

# The table cells
grid [ttk::combobox .f.cb] -row 1 -column 1 -sticky news
for {set row 1} {$row < 5} {incr row} {
    for {set col 1} {$col < 5} {incr col} {
        # Cell 1,1 already has the combobox. Skip it.
        if {($row == 1) && ($col == 1)} continue
        set id r[set row]c[set col]
        grid [entry .f.$id -relief groove -bd 1] -row $row -column $col -sticky news
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, i made a mistake to use "-create", thanks very much, that's should be "-window". I should to read document more carefully...thanks again!